How to connect and query Neo4j Database on Apache Drill?
I am using Apache Drill and Neo4j Database for a project. The database needs to be connected to Drill and I should be able to query the data from Apache Drill.
I have copied and pasted neo4j-driver-4.0.10 into the 3rd party folder for jars. Then, I have created a connection with my Neo4j Database on Apache Drill. Below is the config with the storage name as collisions:
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "driver": "org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver",
  "url": "jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost:7687",
  "username": "neo4j",
  "password": "neo4j",
  "authMode": "SHARED_USER",
  "writerBatchSize": 10000,
  "enabled": true
}

Then when I try to query from the console with this query:
select * from collisions.crashes limit 10;

I get the error:
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method getStatement in class org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jResultSet is not yet implemented.
Warning   UserRemoteException :     PLUGIN ERROR: Failed to load schema for schema collisions
    
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PLUGIN ERROR: Failed to load schema for schema collisions

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method getStatement in class org.neo4j.jdbc.Neo4jResultSet is not yet implemented.


[Error Id: 108138ec-05d7-41af-b7c2-f954798256d8 ]

The data is loaded onto the Neo4j database successfully and I am able to query it from the Neo4j Browser. But why is this error showing up. I couldn't find any other useful question or resource to debug this issue. Can someone help me with this?

The free Neo4J JDBC driver doesn't understand SQL, only Cypher, so it looks like you'd need the non-free BI Connector.
